# Beamer - How do you write items after columns. When I try to use itemize. The items are appearing in the first column alone

Tags: beamer, itemize, columns

After `\end{columns}`, I want to include some items but utilize the entire frame horizontally. Currently, the items are only appearing in the first column.

[image]

```
\begin{frame}{VSry}
    \framesubtitle{PSnk}

    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.33\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{Image1.png}
                \caption{Network Topology}
            \end{figure}
        
        \column{0.33\textwidth} 
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{Image3.png}
                \caption{Un-damped Oscillations}
            \end{figure}
        
        \column{0.33\textwidth} 
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{Image3.png}
                \caption{Damped Oscillations}
            \end{figure}
       % \columnbreak
    \end{columns}
    

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Something 
        \item SOmething 
    \end{itemize}


\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  What kind of output do you expect? Probably, a sketch of the desired output would help clarify? With the code you provided so far, I can't reproduce the issue "The items are appearing in the first column alone". If I add more text than just the word "something" to each `\item`, the text used the entire width of the frame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW9Jr.png